# String initialization with arabic letters in source code

Tags: c++, unicode, arabic

I have an issue with using arabic letters in my source code.
I want to initialize my string with arabic letters analog to latin, but I can't save my source code in unicode. How can I initialize the string by using unicode numbers?

```
CStringEx letters0 = L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

CStringEx letters1 = L"رزطظكلمنصض";
```

I've tried this, but no luck so far.

```
CStringEx letters1 = { 'ا', 'أ', 'إ', 'آ', 'ى', 'ئ', 'ب', 'ت', 'ث', 'ج', 'ح', 'خ', 'د', 'ذ'};
```

Comment: Why can't you save it in "unicode"? I assume you really mean UTF-16LE. I'm going to guess you use source control which won't diff properly with zero bytes in the source, so use UTF-8.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I'm going be brutally honest, I've got no idea what's going on here. I just copied the code part into another texteditor and changed the encoding to UTF-8 and pasted it into the source again. Now it works, before it just garbled up the text.

Comment: If you want to avoid dealing with the source code encoding altogether you could try using universal character names `'\Uxxxxxxxx'`

Comment: @SunKnight0, that is a 'solution', but it doesn't really resolve his issue and makes reading the 'text' (by a human) next to impossible.

Comment: I agree that the text becomes non human readable but it absolutely solves the expressed problem of: "I want to initialize my string with arabic letters analog to latin, but I can't save my source code in Unicode".

Comment: @SunKnight0 I was acutally looking for something like Universal character names, thank you very much. If you want to post a short answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: What is your compiler? On MSVC I think it will also work if you save the file as *UTF-8 with BOM*.

Comment: @roeland Yes, it does, but I have experienced issues with the application which were fixed by using universal character names. It's hard to do anyway when you're not an Arabic speaker with the right-to-left style. Especially with mixed latin/arabic letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as answer per request of the OP:

A relatively easy way to include Unicode characters inside non-Unicode source code is to use universal character names. These take the form: '\Uxxxxxxxx'. The code may be 4 or 8 characters long.

You may also find this tool useful:
http://unicode.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php

It seems to work with your example text.